# Z-Index with Bootstrap: Image Still In Front of Text

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an instance on my site where an image should lay behind a text form, but only the labels are showing. I set the `z-index` of the appropriate divs inline (instead of using CSS) and the site overall uses `bootstrap`.  The `erb` is like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%; z-index: 0 !important">
  <%= image_tag 'background_new_recipe.jpg', style: "height: 100vh" %>
</div>

<div class="container" style="height: 500px; margin-top: -500px; z-index: 100 !important">
  <%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Recipe Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.label "Steps to Deliciousness" %>
    <%= f.text_area :instructions, class: "form-control", style: "height: 300px" %>

    <%= f.label "This Recipe Works With:" %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :chicken %>
      <%= f.label "Chicken", style: "margin-left: 10px; color: red" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :beef %>
      <%= f.label "Beef", style: "margin-left: 10px; color: red" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :fish %>
      <%= f.label "Fish", style: "margin-left: 10px; color: red" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :other_meat %>
      <%= f.label "Other Types of Meat", style: "margin-left: 10px; color: red" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :veggies %>
      <%= f.label "Vegetables", style: "margin-left: 10px; color: red" %>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Share My Delicious Creation", action: :create, class: "btn btn-manly" %></div>
  <% end %>
</div> <!-- container -->
```

And right now it is rendering like this:
[image: Sample Image]

Any ideas how to get this to display properly?

Comment: Are you applying `position:relative` to any of these items?  The `z-index` property only works on positioned elements.

Comment: @RobertC, that was it!  I added `position: relative` to both of them and it appeared perfectly.  If you post it as an answer I'll happily approve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend reviewing the `z-index` property and its requirements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Specifically, `z-index` only functions on positioned elements (i.e. `fixed`, `relative`, `absolute`, `static`, etc).